# Commutation relations in Quantum Field Theory

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, fourier-transform, integration, commutator

\begin{align}
[a, a^\dagger] =&
\left[\int d^3 x e^{-ikx} (\omega \phi(x) + i \Pi^\dagger(x)), \int d^3 x' e^{ikx'} (\omega \phi^\dagger(x') - i \Pi(x')) \right] \\
=& \int d^3x \, d^3x' \, e^{-i(k-k')x} \left[ \omega \phi(x) + i \Pi^\dagger(x) , \omega \phi^\dagger(x') - i \Pi(x') \right]
\end{align}

Could someone please let me understand how the transition from the first step to the second step was made? Specifically I want to know how the exponential factor came about, that is how did one introduce $k'$ (is there some Lorentz transformation involved)?

Ref: Srednicki Chapter 3

Comment: I mean, this isn't anything special about this particular situation. If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are scalars, then $[\alpha\hat{A},\beta\hat{B}]$ = $\alpha\beta[\hat{A},\hat{B}]$, which you can show very easily by expanding the commutator and factoring out the c-numbers $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Comment: I get that, I want to know how instead of $\exp(-ikx+ikx')$ he got $\exp-i(k-k')x$ in the second line

Comment: It's probably a typo.

Comment: @Javier: The typo seems to be OP's, not Sred's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, what he is considering in his eq. (3.29) [I am using the 2014 edition] is the commutator of $a(\mathbf{k})$ and $a^\dagger(\mathbf{k'})$. His eq. (3.21) reads:
$$a(\mathbf{k}) = \int d^3 x\, e^{-ikx}\Big(i \Pi(x)+\omega \phi(x)\Big)\,.$$

Hence, what you are computing is actually:
\begin{align}
[a(\mathbf{k}),a^\dagger(\mathbf{k'})] &= \bigg[\int d^3 x\, e^{-ikx}\Big(i \Pi(x)+\omega \phi(x)\Big),\int d^3 x'\, e^{ik'x'}\Big(-i \Pi(x')+\omega \phi(x')\Big)\bigg]
\\ &= \int d^3 x \, d^3 x'\, e^{-i(kx-k'x')}
\Big[i \Pi(x)+\omega \phi(x),-i \Pi(x')+\omega \phi(x')\Big]\,.
\end{align}

He is considering a real field, $\phi^\dagger(x) = \phi(x)$ and $\Pi^\dagger(x) = \Pi(x)$. One can now make use of his eqs. (3.28), namely:
\begin{align}
\Big[\phi(\mathbf{x},t),\phi(\mathbf{x'},t)\Big]
 &= 0 \\
\Big[\Pi(\mathbf{x},t),\Pi(\mathbf{x'},t)\Big]
 &= 0 \\
\Big[\phi(\mathbf{x},t),\Pi(\mathbf{x'},t)\Big]
 &= i \delta^3(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x'})\,.
\end{align}

In particular, the last one will force $\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{x'}$ under the integrals and you will finally get what you expected.